# Java generation a random number in a specific range?

Tags: java, random

I want to create a field variable that is random from 0.5 – 1.0.

```
private double traction = // ???
```

Comment: You can read the docs for random number generator class [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java possesses the function `Math.random()` which returns [a number that varies between 0 and 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29). Therefore, if you want a random number to vary between 0.5 and 1 only, you need to scale this number by half so that it only varies between 0 and 0.5, and then add this to the minimum value in your range, 0.5.

```
private double traction = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.5;
```